# Loop over dynamically changing list

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, pseudocode

What would be a good approach/algorithm to allow me to loop over a dynamically changing list.

- This list can contain duplicates
- I only need the next element after the current element. i.e if I'm currently on `a[n]` in the next iteration, I want `a[n]` regardless

Currently I tried doing this (pseudo-code) which is pretty trivial
However, It doesn't work with duplicates

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("e");

int currentItem = "a";

function nextItem(){
    int index = findIndex(currentItem);
    currentItem = list[index+1];
    return currentItem;
}

print(nextItem())  #b
print(nextItem())  #c
list.addAt(3, "z")  #add z at the 3rd index
print(nextItem())  #z
print(nextItem())  #d
print(nextItem()) #e
```

I'm thinking about using a linked list for this problem. Would you recommend a different solution or is a linked list the only way?

Edit:
By dynamically changing, I mean a list whoes content can be moddified in the middle of a 'loop' i.e a nextItem() call. Assume a single thread only.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line return c and not d? Also, i don't understand how, in the first call to `nextItem()`, `list[6]` (since currentItem = 5) would throw an error, wouldn't it, since it doesn't exist? Unless you mean to loop back to the first element when it reaches the end of the list.

Comment: @Ashwin_Nair yes your right. I just corrected my error. I had the list filled with number at first and then changed it to letters since I felt it was confusing. Also currentItem is the element in the list and not the index

Comment: If i were you, I'd change my currentItem to use an index...that way you needn't worry about duplicates. I'll add a C# implementation as an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by a dynamically changing list? You mean you have a list and in a different thread, items are constantly being added and removed from it? Please add more exposition so we can help you.

Comment: @Hatefiend added clarification to the question

Answer (score 0):

This is a C# implementation. It goes back to the start once it reaches the end of the loop. You could modify this to throw an exception or any other action at the end.
   In your example, although you use a list element as your `currentItem`, the fact that it's a listElement only matters the very first time.

```
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    int currentItem = 5; // or InitializeCurrentItem {indexOf(listElementToSearchFor);}
    static string nextItem()
    {
        //Handle case where the end of the loop is reached
        if (currentItem == list.Count) currentItem = 0;
        //Ensure current item is updated
        return list[currentItem++];
    }

    void Main()
    {

        list.Add("a");
        list.Add("b");
        list.Add("c");
        list.Add("d");
        list.Add("e");

        Console.WriteLine(nextItem());  //a
        Console.WriteLine(nextItem());  //b
        list.Insert(2, "z"); //add z at the 2nd index
        Console.WriteLine(nextItem());  //z
        Console.WriteLine(nextItem());  //c
        Console.WriteLine(nextItem());  //d
        Console.WriteLine(nextItem());  //e
        Console.WriteLine(nextItem());  //a
}
```

Comment: This wont work if you add an item before the currentItem. Eg `list.Insert(0, "z")`

Comment: I'm not sure i understand . suppose your list is `{a,b,c,d,e}` and you `nextItem` to `b` (the second element) and then, you add `z` to the beginning, making your list `{z,a,b,c,d,e}`, the `nextItem` will be the third element which in this case is `b` once more. Are you expecting some other output?

Comment: Yes, the ouput should be "c". Not "b" again

Comment: @Krimson, I'd add all your expectations as expected outputs to your question. Make sure you have outputs for all cases so potential answers match up with your expected outcomes.